What are the 4 lowest-order Feynman Diagrams for + − → + − scattering?
I have an exercise which asks me for the 4 lowest order Feynman diagrams of + − → + −. However, I can only come up with two:

What could be the two other LOWEST order Feynman diagrams?

In QED, these are the only two. Under the electroweak theory, there is an identical set which exchange $Z$'s instead of $\gamma$'s.
